# Jquery .slice chars from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var obj = $(".yt-simple-endpoint.inline-block.style-scope.ytd-thumbnail")
        console.log("slicing obj " + obj[0].slice(32, 43));
```

obj is a array that contains youtube links. It includes around 32 youtube links if you are at youtube.com main page. So what I am trying to do here is, choose `obj[0]`"First youtube url in that array and slice only the part that comes after watch?v=.

However when I try this I get this error message: "contentscript.js:137 Uncaught TypeError: obj[0].slice is not a function
    at contentscript.js:137"

Comment: Can you add more  code? What are the contents of `url1`, 2 and 3?

Comment: Let's say that they are just random youtube links.
https://www.youtube.com/watch=dfgdr
what I basically want to do is cut only the watch=* from everyarray

Comment: @Xardas105 then state that in your question. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: Your error is because you are trying to `slice` a `string`. `slice` is an array function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract some characters from the first entry in the array, you could indeed use `urls[0]` to get the first entry from the array. You may want to verify its existance.

To extract some characters you can use substr. i.e. (watch id from YT link)

```js
  var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oh3zMzmwsCA";
  
  var urls = [url];
  first_url = urls[0];
  var myRegexp = /watch\?v=(.{11})/g;
  var match = myRegexp.exec(first_url);
  console.log(match[1]); // abc
```

The exec function returns all the matches found based on the regex. For each so called "group", determined by '(' & ')' as seen around the .{11} another array entry will be created when matched.

In addition to those matches, the first element will always be the full match of the regex.

The `\?` will prevent the regex from seeing the '?' as a regex operator. Meaning it will match the literal '?' character.

Comment: It worked with your code, thanks. Could you explain the code tho? Why exactly is this in array? "match[1]"

Also why \? in the link? Is it to disgunish ? from another command?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comments, you want to extract the video url from youtube links.

To get querystring parameters from a url, you can use the solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/4802649).

Then, to get the `v` part of the url, do this:

```js
var urls = [
  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ',
  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fndeDfaWCg',
  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPYZpwSpKmA'
];

var firstLink = getParameterByName('v', urls[0]);

document.write(firstLink);



function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) {
    url = window.location.href
  }
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) {
    return null
  }
  if (!results[2]) {
    return ''
  }
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "))
}
```